# Multiple CSS classes with Less

Tags: html, css, less

I am fairly new Less and have been trying to get a jQuery plugin to work with my custom CSS generated via Less. Basically, what I have is the following html generated by a plugin:

```
 <div class="classA class B" ....>
      <div class="classC classD"  ....>
           <div class="classE classF" ....>
           ..........
```

I am not sure how to structure my Less file in order to generate CSS that matches the above.

I have tried:

```
     .classA {
       ......
        &.classB  {
          .....
              &.classC {

               ....and so on
```

but it generates the following CSS:

```
.classA {...}
.classA.classB {....} /*This does not include the CSS of classA */
.classA.classB.classC {.....} /*This does not include CSS of classA or classB*/
 ...
```

The plain CSS is fairly easy to write :

```
 .classA {.....}
 .classB {.....}
```

and when I write 
        
        
        
how do I achieve the above using Less? Is there a simple way to achieve this without using functions or extends?

Comment: That's what `&` does in less. If you want the output to be  `.classA {.....}
 .classB {.....}` don't use `&`.  The "plain CSS" will work in less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesting elements in less has the result you're describing when adding the `&` : you specify the selector that uniquely matches with that parent and child class (.classA.classB in CSS ),

to do what you're asking

```
  .classA {.....}
  .classB {.....}
```

you simply shouldn't nest_

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to *inherit* styles of one class by another one, you can use [mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature):

```css
.foo() {
    background: #ccc;
}

.bar {
    .foo;
    color: #000;
}
```

Output CSS:

```css
.bar {
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
}
```